# Disk failing during installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, gparted

I have been trying to install Ubuntu for 2 days, it seems problem with my hard disks. Gparted shows **Input/output error during read on /dev/sda**.

*History*

I had a dual booted system, both OS was unabled to start, then I formatted whole hard drive then start using Ubuntu, 2 days ago I ran a program in **jupyter notebook** which used my 100% CPU and 86% RAM while running. PC got slow very hot that time. So I rebooted but it starts failing. Then I tried to install **ubuntu again!** which was unsuccessful cause it partition can't be done. Then I tried with one windows 10 iso file, but installation fails here too, but I partitioned HDD. Now from live cd Gparted shows **Input/output error during read on /dev/sda**.

[Gparted Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIVmk.png)

['sudo fdisk -l' command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WznI2.png)

Full text here -> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RdSsyVGK45/

Answer (score 1):

Get a new drive. It has chosen this time to die.

Comment: This is my smartmontool output -> https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rrntgrcp4F/

Comment: added two file in comment and question, please have a look.

Comment: SMART does not always find errors. If your drive fails (which is what "Input/output error during read on /dev/sda" means), it fails, and it's time to replace it. It's five years old !

Comment: Okey. but how to you find the hard disk age? I'm just curious.

Comment: Original ship date. It's an old design and not very popular anymore.